# Angular Selenium E2E tests: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'results.64820.json'

Tags: angular, typescript, selenium, protractor, cucumber

For Angular e2e tests, `Protractor` (more specifically, `selenium webdriver`) is proving to be a nightmare to maintain on any operating system. Only one developer on our team has working `e2e tests` locally.

After fixing a slew of prior Selenium errors, I now get this beauty:

```
[22:13:32] I/testLogger - [chrome #01-2] PID: 64023
[chrome #01-2] Specs: /myFilePath/e2e/src/myE2ETest.feature
[chrome #01-2] 
[chrome #01-2] [22:13:24] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[chrome #01-2] [22:13:32] I/runnerCli - ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/myFilePath/e2e/e2e/reporting/protractor-cucumber-framework/results.64023.json'

[22:13:32] I/testLogger - 

[22:13:32] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[22:13:32] I/launcher - 4 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[22:13:32] I/testLogger -
```

We're using `Cucumber` along with `Protractor`. I do notice that in `reporting/protractor-cucumber-framework`, there is no file `results.64023.json` - no files at all in fact. There are only files one level up: `/reporting/results.json` and `/reporting/results.xml`

Any ideas of what to do here? I'm not really sure how to translate this error. This really may be my last straw with `Protractor` - probably time to move over to `Cypress`.

Comment: why it's seeing like this `/myFilePath/e2e/e2e/`. did you set a path somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Ahh - sometimes all it takes is a second set of eyes. I see that we're setting that file path in protractor.conf.js. Removing the extraneous e2e/ fixed it for me. Thank you @KishanVaishnani.